# Autofilter to copy and paste to different sheet based on 2 criterias

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not really sure how to use Autofilter for this but I am creating a new worksheet and I'm trying to filter another sheet based on two criterias. I then need to copy the values from only 2 of the columns from that worksheet to the new worksheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set sheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))

ActiveSheet.Range("A11").Value = "Projects in Loss:"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fielding").Activate

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fielding").Activate

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Selection.AutoFilter field:=15,   
Criteria:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Target).Range("A3").Value, Operator:=xlAnd

Selection.AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria:="<30%" & ">0"

ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.sheet ("Fielding")
ActiveSheet.Columns("U").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It keeps giving me a run time error '1004'. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or could direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Selection.AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria:="<30%" & ">0"
> ```

The way to do this is by putting two different criteria with `xlAnd` operator

```
Selection.AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=">0", Operator=xlAnd, Criteria2 = "<0.3"
```

Also, there's no parameter `Criteria` in the `AutoFilter` method. It's `Criteria1` and optionally another parameter `Criteria2` (change `Criteria` to `Criteria1` at other places in your code).

Working with `Selection` is hazardous and source of bugs. You should really try to rewrite your code without the `Selection` stuff. Take a look at [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thank you this helped!! I avoided using select and made the changes you said!